# Angular Checkbox checked if Value is Yes

Tags: angularjs

```
 <td><label> <input value="{{track.Visible}}" type="checkbox"></label></td>
```

Id like to check a checkbox if {{track.Visible}} = "Yes"

I dont have the option of changing DataType to Boolean.

Other examples i look at use a Boolean

```
<td>{{track.Visible}}</td>
<td><label> <input ng-checked="track.Visible==='YES'?true:false" type="checkbox"></label></td>
<td><label> <input ng-model="track.Visible" ng-true-value="YES" type="checkbox"></label></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-true-value`, like below

```
<td><label> <input ng-model="track.Visible" ng-true-value="Yes" type="checkbox"></label></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v27t9rq1/ check this fiddle

Comment: This compiles but doesnt check any boxes

Comment: I can see that it works in JSFiddle but doesnt work for me. Maybe my data is wrong. Ill attach image.